# Multiple retrofit dependent requests

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a model like this (and I can not change)

```
public class Container {
   private int id
   private List<Item> items
}
```

The item class looks like this:

```
public class Item {
    private int something;
    private Owner owner;
}
```

And The owner class looks like this:

```
public class Owner {
    private String login;
    private String url;
    private String name;
}
```

The problem is that one request (not my, can not change) gets a Container with all items and its owner only with the login and url attributes (in this example). The name attribute is not retrieved on this call.

I have to make another request with the login parameter to get the name of the owner. And the update my model to populate this attribute so I can use the list of items (with the owner name) later on.

I new with retrofit and don´t know about rxJava, but I look around and could not figured this out.

This is what I have so far:

An interface

```
public interface SomeService {
     @GET("somerlToGetContainerWithItems")
     Observable<Container> getContainer();

     @GET("url/{login}")
     Observable<Owner> getOwner(@Path("login") String login);
}
```

An api client

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
}
```

And on the main activity, I have this code;

```
service = client.getClient().create(Service.class);

private Observable<Container> getContainer() {
    return service.getContainer();
}

private Observable<Owner> getOwner(Item item) {
    return service.getOwner(item.getOwner().getLogin());
}

getContainer()
            .flatMap(r-> Observable.just(r.getItems()))
            .flatMap(new Func1<Item, Observable<? extends Owner>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<? extends Owner> call(Item response) {
                    return getOwner(response);
                }
            }, new Func2<List<Item>, Owner, List<Item>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Item> call(List<Item> items, Owner owner) {
                  // dont know how to return the list of items again
                  // with the owner name
                }
            });
```

So basically I have to make the second request based on each item and than return this list of items but with the owner name.

Comment: Like this https://gitlab.com/snippets/1682034??

Comment: I'm getting a lot of errors like "Object can not be applied to Observable" and vice versa. I'm using retrofit 2 and rxjava 2. Is that correct?

Comment: in rxjava2 you would Function instead of Func1. Any way i ran the sample in the gist works although the data is not from network.

Comment: I could not make this code "compilable". I got errors on methods "from", "subscribe" and the first "Func1". Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you just try the java code in the gist and forget android for testing??

Answer (score 0):

[KOTLIN]
For Future people :)

```
    class PanelActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_panel)
    
            val token = intent.extras?.getString(TOKEN)
            val bearerToken = "Bearer $token"
            val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    
// here I use my second request
            postItem(token, bearerToken, sharedPreferences)
    
    
        }
    
        fun postItem(token: String?, bearerToken: String, sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) {
            val id= getID(token)
    
            RetrofitClient.sendNetworkRequest.getId(id.toString(), bearerToken).enqueue(object : Callback<Your_Object> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<Your_Object>,
                    response: Response<Your_Object>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                       
                   
                        preparePost(token, bearerToken, sharedPreferences)
                 
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Your_Object>, t: Throwable) {
                    // on failure
                }
            })
        }
    
        fun preparePost(token: String?, bearerToken: String, sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences){
    
           
    
            RetrofitClient.sendNetworkRequest.getAllRides(id, bearerToken).enqueue(object : Callback<Your_Object> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Your_Object>, response:Response<Your_Object>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                       // on response if successful
                        } 
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Your_Object>, t: Throwable) {
                   // on failure
                }
            })
    
        }
```

As you see, My need was to post request, put some id to sharedPreferences, and use this saved value into new request.
Just make other function and invoke on Response into first request.